# Display captured image

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-image

I am trying to take a picture in from my camera and put it on my application as a thumbnail, it successfully lets me take a photo but will not go further than that, it only seems to output the image which is the logo of my application.

Here is the code:

```
public void breakfastPicture(){

    bPicButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bPicButton);
    bPicButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "breakfast.jpg");
            Uri photoPath = Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoPath);

            // start camera activity
            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

     if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode== RESULT_OK && intent != null){

            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            ImageView bThumbnail = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bThumbnail);

            Bitmap bBitMap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            bThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bBitMap);

        }
 }
```

Comment: review http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html, for example, notice the code that ensures the photoPath exists and is writable?  For now, try not including the EXTRA_OUTPUT extra and see if this makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
Bitmap bBitMap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
```

Try using:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"breakfast.jpg");
ImageView bThumbnail = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bThumbnail);
Bitmap bBitMap = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), 1000, 700);


bThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bBitMap);
```

decodeSampleBitmapFromFile method:

```
 public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // BEST QUALITY MATCH

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize, Raw height and widht of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight)
    {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height/(float)reqHeight);
    }
    int expectedWidth = width/inSampleSize;

    if(expectedWidth > reqWidth)
    {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width/(float)reqWidth);
    }

    options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
}
```